# error: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_Employer',

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, header, composite

Along with Errors "C4430 missing type specifier int assumed" x2 , and C2061 syntax Errors Employer
        Code:

Person.h

```
    #ifndef PERSON_H
    #define PERSON_H
    #include "employer.h"
    #include "position.h"
    #include <QTextStream>
    #include <QString>

    class Person
    {
    private:
        QString m_Name;
        bool m_Employed;
```

Getting a syntax error here and missing type specifier:

```
        Employer m_Employer;
        Position m_Position;
    public:
        Person();
        Person(QString name);
        QString toString();
```

syntax error here

```
        void setPosition(Employer &newC, Position &newP);
        void getPosition();
        void getEmployer();
    };

    #endif // PERSON_H
```

Person.cpp

```
    #include "person.h"

    Person::Person()
    {
        m_Name = "";
    }

    Person::Person(QString name)
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }

    QString Person::toString()
    {
        return "";
    }

    void Person::setPosition(Employer &newC, Position &newP)
    {

    }
```

Employer.h file:

```
    #ifndef EMPLOYER_H
    #define EMPLOYER_H
    #include "person.h"
    #include <QTextStream>
    #include<QString>


    class Employer
    {
    private:
        QString m_Name;
        QString m_Market;

    public:
        Employer();
        Employer(QString name, QString market);
```

Syntax Error Here

```
        bool hire(Person &newHire, Position pos);
        QString toString();
    };

    #endif // EMPLOYER_H
```

Employer.cpp

```
    #include "employer.h"

    Employer::Employer()
    {

    }

    Employer::Employer(QString name, QString market)
    {
        m_Name = name;
        m_Market = market;
    }

    QString toString()
    {
     return "";
    }
```

Position.h file:

```
    #ifndef POSITION_H
    #define POSITION_H
    #include <QTextStream>
    #include <QString>

    class Position
    {
    private:
        QString m_Name;
        QString m_Description;

    public:
        Position();
        Position(QString name, QString description);
        ~Position();
        QString toString();
    };

    #endif // POSITION_H
```

Position.cpp file:

```
    #include "position.h"

    Position::Position()
    {
        m_Name = "";
        m_Description = "";
    }
    Position::Position(QString name, Qstring description)
    {
         m_Name = name;
         m_Description = description;
    }

    QString Position::toString()
    {
      return "";
    }
```

I have a main as well but it is not in use, i wanted to fix these problems before any more show up
I've been looking this over and i cant seem to find out whats wrong, Please any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. `Person.h` includes `Employer.h` which includes `Person.h`.

You can forward declare `Person` in `Employer.h`:

Add `class Person;` to `Employee.h` and move the `#include "person.h"` to `Employee.cpp`

What the error comes from is when the compiler goes to compile `Employer.cpp`(or `Person.cpp` it doesn't matter which one), it includes the `Employer.h`, which tells the compiler to include `Person.h`, which tells the compiler to include `Employer.h`, but this time the include guards kick in and it stops the contents of `Employer.h` being included again. So it starts to compile `Person.h` with no mention of `Employer`. Therefore it is an unknown type when it sees `Employer m_employer`.